# Question about an Obama's statement on Iraq

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here's a quote from an Obama's statement on Iraq.

"But what we've also seen I think is a wake-up call for a lot of Iraqis
inside of Baghdad recognizing that we're going to have to rethink how we do business
if we're going to hold our country together."
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2014/08/09/statement-president-iraq

I wonder what "we" means in "we're going to have to rethink...".
Does it mean Americans or Iraqis?
I also wonder who recognizes that "we're going to have to rethink...".
Iraqis or Obama?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, it seems that *we* changes meaning in the middle of the sentence.

Throughout the speech, *we* is used in a generic way, referring quite loosely to "we, the U.S. administration" and / or "we, the American people" or even "we, the world in general".
It is used in the same way I could ask "what do *we* call a long yellow fruit?"

However, the moment he mentions what Iraqis inside of Baghdad are thinking, the *we* he uses is part of the indirect speech (or rather, "reported thought"). *We* all of a sudden refers to the Iraqis.

It would have been more clear if he would have used direct speech (thought) like this:

> But what we've also seen I think is a wake-up call for a lot of Iraqis inside of Baghdad recognizing: "we're going to have to rethink how we do business if we're going to hold our country together."

The only give-away for the change of meaning of *we* is the fact that "our country", which has to be kept "together", can, in this context only refer to Iraq, so people referring to it as *our country* have to be Iraqis.

Al in all, the sentence does not deserve a prize for clarity or style, in my opinion.

Comment: "What do we call a long yellow fruit?" "Yellow straightneck squash, maybe." :-)